# Dynamically Add Drop down Form Field

Tags: javascript

In my code I have a  js file to Dynamically Add and Remove Form Fields.I need a drop down form field in which each option  values should select from database. Please help me.Thanks In advance.

Comment: What is the database structure and what fields should be used for drop down?

Comment: Table fields are given below .
id,qualification,descriptions,status
from that I need qualification in option and id as value its value